# Write newline (\n) in a file in python opened in byte mode

Tags: python-3.x, file, utf-8, python-unicode

I was trying to write unicode text in a file in python. I was perfectly able to write unicode text in a file using *encode("utf-8")*. But while i was trying to write newline between some unicode text it didn't work. The first code snippet opened in w mode works perfectly while the second snippet opened in byte (wb) mode doesn't work.

I am giving the following code as an example and hoping someone has the solution.

```
fw = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.txt", "w")
newline = "\n\n\n Hello"
fw.write(newline)
fw.close()

fw = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b.txt", "wb")
newline = "\n\n\n Hello".encode("utf-8")
fw.write(newline)
fw.close()
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The second snippet looks ok to me. Do you get an error message, or is the output different from what you expect?

Comment: Yea, the second snippet gives an error. 
Error Message: 
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. You might have got it with a different piece of code. Please provide the full stacktrace (in the answer, not comment, please).

Comment: You are right Lenz. I was getting this error message for null object. And I opened both files in notepad which saves these files in ANSI format. That's why file b.txt only shows "Hello" while a.txt shows newline as well as "Hello". But opening both files in Notepad++ shows text perfectly.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with encoding, but with newline conventions (`\r\n` on Windows, `\n` everywhere else). For files opened in text mode on Windows, Python replaces `\n` with `\r\n` when writing, but not for binary files. And notepad refuses to interpret a sole `\n` as a newline, that's why you don't see it.

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18346476)

Comment: Okay but it will work fine i think, i have tried then only provided answer

Comment: Isn't it possible without using any library file? Actually I am looking for something default without using any library.

Comment: @Mamunahmed33 The codecs module is in the standard library, so it's always available. However, in this case you can actually avoid the codecs library, since the built-in `open` function also accepts an `encoding=...` parameter.